# Verify git integrity

Tags: git, compare, repository

Soon sourceforge will restore my projects git repository.

I have a 'pull -a' from the day before it disappeared; so I am confident that I have no data loss on my local copy.

Would I would like to do is do a "deep compare" of my local copy with the soon-to-be.restored sourceforge master repo so as to make sure that we are *absolutely* in sync before commit any new changes. Test that the histories agree; the same objects with the same hashes; and anything else that might prevent future grief.

Something like (a non-existent) "git compare-trees --verify ...."

I suppose it might be easier to rename the sourceforge repo, and then push my local copy as the new master, but that strikes me as inelegant.

Comment: You need only compare the hashes of your local and remote branches/tags. Sounds like a good time to move off sourceforge; github, bitbucket etc. Are probably better options.

Comment: If the SHA1 hashes match and your repository passes `git-fsck`, things should be pretty good.

Answer (score 2):

As others mentioned in comments, you really just need to check the SHA-1 values (and run `git fsck` to make it compare the SHA-1 name by which each object is found, to the current SHA-1 of each object<sup>1</sup>).

Because git uses a form of [Merkle Tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merkle_tree), if the SHA-1 for a branch like `master` in one repo matches the SHA-1 for a branch in another repo, you can be reasonably sure<sup>2</sup> that the entire chain of commits is bit-for-bit identical in both repositories.  Hence comparing the output of a simple `git for-each-ref` run on each repository will do the trick.

---

<sup>1</sup>If these don't match internally, you'll see (from [the git-fsck documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-fsck.html#_extracted_diagnostics)):

```
   sha1 mismatch <object>
       The database has an object who’s sha1 doesn’t match the database
       value. This indicates a serious data integrity problem.
```

<sup>2</sup>The chance of an accidental match between any two SHA-1s for different inputs is one in 2<sup>160</sup> (2<sup>160</sup> is a bit over 10<sup>48</sup>, so this is one in 1.465 [quindecillion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Names_of_large_numbers)).  As the number of objects rises, the chance rises rapidly due to the ["birthday problem"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem#Cast_as_a_collision_problem) but for practical purposes, it's rare enough to disregard entirely.  The only way to get a real collision is to do it on purpose, and that's [still too hard](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/2583).